# Blender Camera Clipping Reversal Issues with Freestyle/LineArt Rendering

Tags: rendering, camera, grease-pencil, freestyle, lineart

I've been working on a project in Blender where I attempted to achieve a specific visual effect by intentionally reversing the camera's Clipping Start and Clipping End settings. In particular, I set the Clipping End closer to the camera than the Clipping Start. This approach did help me achieve the desired visual effect, but I've run into a problem: When enabling Freestyle or using the Grease Pencil's LineArt mode, these features seem unable to render correctly.

My guess is that the reversed clipping range is causing the renderer to struggle with correctly identifying and processing the edges and lines in the scene. I've tried a few different setting adjustments but haven't found a suitable solution yet.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue? Or does anyone know how to make Freestyle or LineArt mode work properly while maintaining this unique clipping setting?